# For loop iteration hangs

Tags: java, loops

Okay so i have written two for loops one inside the other and they run. However The out for loop iterates and then hangs.

```
for(int i = 0; i< 500; i++)
{
 for(int j = 0; j< 1; j++)
 { 
  //do some logic
    System.out.println("Looped"); 
 }
}
```

loop runs 12 times and then cursor remains blinking. I am sure the problem is not with the inner loop as it works for the first 12 iterations.

does anyone know why this might happen? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you running this it's fine

Comment: Works for me.  Your bug must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: My guess, the problem lies in "do some logic".

Comment: Hmm, yeah, gotta watch out for that _logic_ stuff.

Comment: Are you running this in a terminal?

Comment: its suppose to run 500 iterations its reaching 12 then cursor hang as the program is running but no out put and the program doesn't end its just there waiting

Comment: i am running in terminal going to try and run in a debugger

Comment: is the amount of "stuff" you are doing dependent on the magnitude of `i`? eg  `2 ^ i` operations? it could be you have a time complexity problem.

Comment: i think i am running out of memory

Comment: thanks for all the help guys greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It is not hanging, the outputs are same for each iteration makes you think it is stopped or whatever. Move your cursor up or scroll up, you will see outputs keep increasing. To verify these, you can change

`System.out.println("Looped");`
to 
`System.out.println("Looped "+i);`

and check again.

Comment: Or better to be double sure:-
`System.out.println("Looped"); to  System.out.println("Looped "+i+","+j);`

Comment: I guess i always equal to 0, but who knows.

Comment: i tried this approach already that how i know its only making it between 4 and 12 iterations before it hangs. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: There is no error in this code. To solve your problem, you might need to show us what is inside `//do some logic`.